# Calculus 2: Shell Method

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I am puzzled with this question because I feel as though I have to integrate this shape with respect to dy. However, the shell method uses x in order to avoid having to find everything in terms of y. Regardless, I tried using the formula V= 2pi * the integral from -4 to -1 of (10-x)* (x^-4). Then I used algebra to find the answer to be 90pi/16. However this is incorrect. If any could offer some assistance that would be wonderful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the radius (that is, the distance between any $x \in [-4,-1]$ and the axis of rotation $x = 4$) is $4 - x$. Hence, we obtain:
$$
V = 2\pi\int_{-4}^{-1}(4 - x)(x^{-4}) \,dx = \frac{57\pi}{16}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I understand the problem better now.